# Mysql slow.log user specific

Tags: mysql, logging, user-management, configuration

I use a `slow.log` logging on my MySQL server, to catch bottlenecks in my script, but at the same time, i use `phpmyadmin` on this server. My script and `phpmyadmin` has different MySQL user accounts and now, when i analyzing the `slow.log` file, i see a lot of spam from `phpmyadmin` queries, is it possible, to configure the MySQL to logging a slow queries only from specific users?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of any options to set up separate slow query logs per user, but many of the log query parsers can be configured to just print for a user, or exclude a user.

https://code.google.com/p/mysql-log-filter/ for example offers the following ways.

> -T=min_query_time
>   -R=min_rows_examined
>
> -ih, --include-host
>   -eh, --exclude-host
>   -iu, --include-user
>   -eu, --exclude-user
>   -iq, --include-query